# Does spark supports shuffling only from disk?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question Spark shuffle. Lets say there are 3 stages of a spark application

Stage 1 is fully independent are they have just some map and filter transformations

Stage 2 is fully independent are they have just some map and filter transformations

Stage 3 has some join statements and agg functions

The output of stage 1 and stage 2  need to be shuffled .

My question is  Does spark store the output of stage 1 and stage 2  in Physical memory or disk memory?

Is it true that data that needs to sent for stage 3 has to be stored in disk memory first and then only it can be shuffled. Basically what i am asking if you want to shuffle the data then it has to stored in disk before we start the shuffle or shuffle can be done from physical memory itself?

Comment: The process of shuffle in spark is writing the shuffle segments to the disk. So to answer your question, yes Spark shuffle only happens via disk.

Comment: Ok. So Does it store all the data to be sent for shuffle in Disk or Does it store in disk  only  for some amount of data which cannot be stored in physical memory ?

Comment: The entire shuffle block is stored on disk.